# Angular Posting not sending

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, post

This is my **index.html** page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
      <form ng-submit="sendPost()">
        <label>Input id</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="id" required/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      {{response}}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my **app.js**:

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.id = "";
    $scope.response = "";
    $scope.sendPost = function() {
        var userDetails = [{"userId":"23848348", "type":"CUSTOMER"}];
        var request = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://thisisatest.testhost.com/userInfo',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'id':$scope.id
            },
            data: $.param({
                json: JSON.stringify({
                    'code':'8388',
                    'userDetails': userDetails
                })
            })
        }
        $http(request)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                /*called for result & error because 200 status*/
                if (data.result) {
                    $scope.response = data.result;
                } else if (data.error) {
                    //handle error here
                }
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                /*handle non 200 statuses*/
            });
    }
})
```

Here's what the json request body is supposed to look like:

```
{
   "code":"8388",
   "userDetails": [
        {          
            "userId": "23848348",        
            "type": "CUSTOMER"
        }
   ]
}
```

But when i input an id in the textbox and hit submit i dont see anything printed in the response area. Any idea what I did wrong here?

Comment: You missed `ng-app="myApp"` in html

Comment: @swapnesh unfortunately that didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The data portion of the request should just be:

```
data: {
    'code':'8388',
    'userDetails': userDetails
}
```